# Spring message in Javascript: cannot display Spanish accent characters properly

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, encoding

I am facing a very general Spring message issue but so far doesn't have a simple solution, so hope everyone here can enlighten me a little bit.

Current Spring MVC application has an issue on properly display Spanish accent characters on javascript alert. The alert message now shows up like this:

```
Por favor elija la fecha de aplicaci&oacute;n
```

but it is supposed to show up like this:

```
Por favor elija la fecha de aplicación
```

above message pops up when user failed the validation, which processed by javascript:

```
alert("<spring:message code='message_miss_duedate' />");
```

but if I put the whole string in Spanish into the javascript:

```
alert("Por favor elija la fecha de aplicación");
```

the output is fine.

Cause of the issue is obvious: the `&Xacute;` is generated by method from Spring message to convert Spanish accent characters to HTML friendly codes, which works fine when parsed by html, however, such code is not recognized by javascript.

So far the 'EncodingFilter' is set to UTF-8

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

and same to the pom setting:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

So, is there anyway to skip the accent character conversion by Spring when using Spring message? Thanks.

Comment: What does the message look like in the alert on the client?

Comment: @nif Thanks, the message just looks like what is described in the message, it supposed to looks like: "Por favor elija la fecha de aplicación", however, javascript failed to intepret it.

Comment: @nif I made some change now the javascript alert still has issue but looks different.

Comment: Try to use the UTF-8 characters directly in the message or encode them using `&#nnnn;` - AFAIK, the HTML entities are not supported in XHTML.

Comment: @nif Thanks do we have a relative simpler solution, I have updated the whole post so hopefully that can help you get more idea about what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

The solution is very simple, use `htmlEscape="false"` in `spring:message`, by default the value is `true` hence the escaping characters

so

```
alert('<spring:message code="message_miss_duedate" htmlEscape="false"/>');
```

now pop up message looks pretty.

### END of UPDATE

Now I have a workaround but not a solution because it has limitation, so I will leave this thread open until there is a general solution:

In the controller using Spring `MessageSource` object to pass the alert message into `uiModel`:

```
Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
uiModel.addAttribute("message_miss_duedate", messageSource.getMessage("message_miss_duedate", null, currentLocale));
```

So in javascript we can get the message like normal JSTL variable

```
alert("${message_miss_duedate}");
```

But like mentioned this approach as limit because it is difficult to handle runtime responding message with variable, especially with code template.